# "Could not connect. Too many connections" Error in MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, runtime-error

I have the following code

```
function openDBConn($params){
    $conn_mode = $params['conn_mode'];
    $db_conn = $params['db_conn'];

    //create connections
    if(empty($db_conn->info)) {
        $db_conn = new mysqli("localhost", $user, $password, "database");
        $db_conn->set_charset('UTF8'); 
        $mysqli_error = $db_conn->connect_error;
    }

    if($mysqli_error !== NULL){ 
        die('Could not connect <br/>'. $mysqli_error); 
    }else{ 
        return $db_conn; 
    }
}

//close db connection
function closeDBConn( $params ){
    $db_conn = $params['db_conn'];
    $db_conn->close;
}

//used as below
$db_conn = openDBConn();

save_new_post( $post_txt, $db_conn );

closeDBConn( array('db_conn'=>$db_conn));
```

From time to time, I get the "Could not connect. Too many connections" error. 
This tends to happen when I have Google bot scanning my website.

This problem seems to have started ever since upgrading to MySQLi from MySQL.
Is there any advice on how ensure all connections are closed?

Thanks

Comment: unless you've explicitly requested a persistent connection, PHP will automatically close connections when the script exits. This means you've probably just got too many simultaneous hits on your site, and your connection limit is too low/doesn't match however many apache child processes you're allowing.

Comment: In your db console Run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%connect%'` to see what max connections are.

Comment: `$db_conn->close;` does nothing. You need `()`.

Comment: ^--« ... http://php.net//manual/en/mysqli.close.php

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase the number of connections to your MySQL server (the default is only 100 and typically each page load consumes one connection)

Edit `/etc/my.cnf`

> max_connections = 250

Then restart MySQL

> service mysqld restart

http://major.io/2007/01/24/increase-mysql-connection-limit/

Comment: What is the advisable number of connections?

Comment: I would suggest between 250 and 500 for a normal web server with normal load. Beyond that, you would probably want to split your database server off from your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Some hosters have a hard limit how many open database connections your are allowed to have. Maybe you want to contact your hoster to know how many you are allowed to open. For websites with hight traffic load more connections can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the server directly or is it a hosted solution?

If you have direct access you can check the mySQL config files to see how many connections are allowed and increase it.

If you don't you might want to contact your webhost about increasing the limit and see if they will comply.

Comment: It is a shared server with mediatemple